# How can I do some actions before grab call files in Astersik?

Tags: asterisk

I use call file in asterisk for auto dialing. How can I do some actions before call ? There is a predial handler in asterisk but it works with dial or followMe application. note that I'm using call file.

Comment: Why don't you just make a special context for your call files to do your actions before actually connecting to peer?

Comment: I am newbie in asterisk.first asterisk calls to recipient and then executes extensions commands.Is that correct ? how can I execute commands in a context before call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new context to execute commands before call, for example:

```
[precall]

exten => _X.,1,NoOp(Precall processing)
same => n,System(echo ${EXTEN} call >> /tmp/call.log)
same => n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
```

And then in your call file:

```
Channel: Local/1000@precall
Context: from-internal
Extension: 2000
```

In this case:

- Asterisk will start in `precall` context at extension `1000,1`
- It will execute `echo 1000 call >> /tmp/call.log` system command
- Call `SIP/1000` and wait for answer
- When `SIP/1000` answer the call, Asterisk goes to `from-internal` context, extension `2000,1`
- If you have common configuration, it will dial number `2000`